# Why do non-accelerating objects exert force on each other?

Tags: forces, mass, acceleration

The equation for force is $\vec{F} = m\vec{a}$, where $\vec{a}$ is *acceleration*. *Acceleration* is a change in *velocity*. However, if an object with *constant velocity* (i.e. 0 acceleration) hits another object, it still exerts a *force* on it.

Why is this? Is there something fundamental that I'm missing here?

Comment: The forces between macroscopic objects are the result of the electromagnetic force and quantum mechanics. Classical mechanics can describe their consequences, but it has nothing to say about their nature.

Comment: You probably meant "acceleration is the *rate of change* of velocity", but just to be sure...

Comment: @AV23 I probably did mean that, but I'm not a mathematician or a physicist - I'm a programmer who's not particularly good with maths or physics.

Comment: You're probably missing the momentum, `p=mv`.

Comment: During a collision, the velocity is **not** constant!

Comment: @sanchises That's not particularly helpful.

Comment: @Pharap I'll elaborate. An object, hitting another object, will indeed exert a force on the other object. However, during that collision, the acceleration is **not** equal to zero! Take two snooker balls - when they collide, they will both have a different velocity *vector* afterwards, which means that acceleration must have taken place. So, your premise that something can hit something else with constant velocity is false (at least, in classical mechanics) - your object will only have constant velocity right up until the moment you hit something else!

Comment: @sanchises "your object will only have constant velocity right up until the moment you hit something else!" At what point do I make a statement that implies that I do not believe this? My question was about where the force came from when the collision happens when both objects have no acceleration. My issue was with the fact that force is defined as mass times velocity, which I took to mean that force is the result of acceleration and mass, but the answer I accepted explained that this was not the case.

Comment: @Pharap Sorry, I couldn't see from your question that you were asking about causality in classical mechanics. Either way, if you think a reply answers your question, be sure to mark it as accepted. ;)

Comment: @sanchises I only just noticed it didn't accept. I must have double clicked or forgot to click after explaining why I was accepting it (on two different answers). I'm starting to regret asking this at physics, people keep trying to give overly complicated answers. Next time I'm going to just ask at programmers or stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\vec{F} = m\vec{a}$ means that an object with a force $\vec{F}$ *exerted upon it* accelerates by an amount $\vec{a}$, not that an object accelerating with $\vec{a}$ *exerts a force* $\vec{F}$ on something else. Typically, the force exerted *by* an object has nothing to do with Newton's second law, but is given by other laws (like Coulomb's law in electrostatics).

But then, you have Newton's third law: every action has an equal and opposite reaction. This means that in a collision, the object that hits another also has an equal and opposite (instantaneous - or not, depending on the duration of collision) force exerted on it by the other. It *does* accelerate when it hits - it's velocity is only constant up to that point. And this acceleration is given by $\vec{a'} = -\frac{\vec{F'}}{m}$, where $\vec{F'}$ is the force *exerted by* the object on the other; and therefore the other exerts an equal and opposite force $-\vec{F'}$ on it, which we can use in Newton's second law.

Comment: Makes sense. I now understand what it is I need to find out to solve the bigger problem that this was part of.

Comment: @Pharap if you insist, I've added in vector notation, which I did leave out originally for simplicity. It does not have much to add to the problem here.

Comment: The vector notation doesn't bother me at all in this case because it doesn't really affect the answer, you were just the only other person using equations in their answer.

Comment: I've decided to accept this answer for two main reasons. Firstly because it has been voted most helpful by others. And secondly I think the clarification that $\vec{F} = m\vec{a}$ means a force causes the acceleration rather than the acceleration causing the force was important and helped my understanding of the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Although an object that moves with constant velocity has no acceleration, it has kinetic energy and it has momentum.

Acceleration is not a conserved quantity.  It is not passed from one object to another.  Momentum and energy, however, are conserved quantities that pass from one object to another.

If a moving object hits a target, kinetic energy will be transferred to the target and may cause the target to gain its own acceleration.  This would be an elastic collision.  The results do not depend on the acceleration of the moving object, but only on its energy and its momentum at the instant of impact.

If the target absorbs all the kinetic energy of the collision and is deformed, turning kinetic into potential energy, this would be an inelastic collision, where kinetic energy is lost, and the target gains no acceleration.

There's a saying in finance that if you want to understand what's happening, "follow the money".  In physics, you could say "follow the energy" (NOT the acceleration).

The momentum of a moving object is the product of its velocity times its mass.  This, also, can be transferred from one object to another, unlike acceleration.

Comment: I say this answer is a better description of what is going on.  Really the OP is interested in the relation $\vec{F} = d\vec{P}/dt$.  Here the force is related to the change in momentum, or for fixed mass, change in velocity in time.

Comment: I think this answer is better than the accepted answer in that it explains things in a way that someone who doesn't understand much physics would be able to comprehend. Plus, it explains that the cause of the acceleration after the collision is indeed energy. However the other answer's clarification that I was misunderstanding the force equation's meaning was vital. If I could accept both I would.

Answer (score 1):

2 points: first, $F=ma$ describes the acceleration of an object due to the *sum* of all forces acting on the object.  If these forces are in different directions, they may partly or fully cancel each other out.  In the case where the object is not accelerating (so it's moving with constant speed in a constant direction, or it's not moving at all), the sum of forces acting on it must be zero.  ($F$ and $a$ should really be vectors $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{a}$).

Second, objects need not be moving to exert forces on each other.  For example, a book on a table exerts a downward force on the table while the table exerts an upward force on the book.  But if there are forces, why isn't the book accelerating?  It's because each force on the book is balanced by an opposite force.  For example, the upward force of the table pushing on the book is balanced by the force of gravity pulling the book down.  However, these two forces don't have to be equal and opposite: they just happen to be so if the book isn't accelerating.  For example, if you cause the table to accelerate upward, then the upward force of the table on the book exceeds the downward gravitational force on the book, and so the book accelerates up with the table.

By the way, the fact that the forces on a non-accelerating object cancel each other out has nothing to do with Newton's 3rd law.  The 3rd law says *every* force is one of an "action-reaction pair" between two objects A and B.  The force of the object A acting on object B is always equal and opposite to the force of object B acting on object A.  Where it gets confusing is that often forces can be equal and opposite even though they are not "action-reaction pairs," for example gravity pulling the book down and the table pushing the book up.  These are not paired forces because one is between book and earth while the other is between book and table.  The "partner" to the force of gravity pulling the book down is actually an equal force of the book pulling the earth up!  Of course this force doesn't produce a measurable acceleration because the earth's mass is so huge.  But in fact, *every* force is one of an action-reaction pair.

Comment: Yes $F$ and $a$ should be vectors, but I don't know how to work latex formatting properly. @AV23 probably left them out for simplicity.

Comment: I wasn't correcting the notation so much as pointing out the importance of the directional nature of the force and acceleration.  For example, if a book sits on a slanted table and does not slide, there are three forces acting on the book: gravity, friction, and the "normal" force of the table pushing on the book.  None of these forces is opposite in direction from any other, yet they all add to zero net force.  That's vector addition.  By the way, in TeX you make a vector like this:  \vec{F}.

Comment: In this case I don't think direction is important. If you restricted travel to just the X axis and assume both objects to be boxes the issue in the question and the chosen answer still apply. I discovered that from AV23's edit.